# Why is Christina Perri pronouncing "closer" as "cloSSer"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, accent, phonology

In [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfTS7gM7zQ0) at 0:58, Christina Perri pronounced the word "closer" with an S sound: *clo[**s**]er*

I have always pronounced and heard it with a Z sound. Is the pronunciation of "closer" in this video specific to her accent? It is strange.

Comment: reading her name I think she is Italian(i'm italian too and never heard about her),  and I think it is derived from this.

Comment: @Liiuc: How? She pronounces it correctly though. The OP confused close (v) and close (adj) and thought that the adj had a voiced sound (/z/).

Comment: In English orthography, doubling a consonant after a vowel is used to indicate that the vowel is short. So while you apparently intended the spelling "closser" to emphasize the "s" sound, it instead makes it look like you're saying that the "o" is short.

Comment: @Acccumulation indeed. But is there a way to unambiguously spell the intended pronunciation without shortening the "o"?

Comment: @Ruslan: It could be spelt **Clo[s]er**; [brackets] represent actual sounds

Comment: @Liiuc from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christina_Perri : born in Pennsylvania, Polish mother, Italian father, went to school in the US. I'd guess she is an US English native speaker. (Also, I don't think an Italian speaker would use an /s/ sound here).

Comment: tl;dr It's not strange; you've been saying it wrong this whole time!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Christina Perri pronounces it correctly and that's not restricted to American English. As far as I know, the pronunciation of *closer* (adj) with an /s/ is the correct pronunciation in almost all varieties of English.

#### Pronunciation of *close* (verb)

I think you're confusing *close* (adj) and *close* (verb). The verb *close* is pronounced [kləʊ**z**]—with a /z/.

#### Pronunciation of *close* (adj)

The adjective *close*, its comparative and superlative are pronounced with an /s/:

- close → [kləʊ**s**]
- closer → [ˈkləʊ**s**ə]
- closest → [ˈkləʊ**s**ɪst]

#### Pronunciation of *closer* (noun)

There's also a noun '[closer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/closer)', which is pronounced with a /z/ sound: [ˈkləʊzə]

### *Clo[**s**]e enough to clo[**z**]e the door*???

Both the 'close's in the sentence above are pronounced with a different sound. The reason for this idiosyncrasy is...... (welp, don't get me started on that) Old English's *fricative voicing*.

There were three fricative phonemes, /f, θ, s/ in Old English. Old English had a phonetic property called *fricative voicing*, whereby fricatives—*s, f, þ ~ ð*<sup>**1**</sup>—became voiced when they were flanked by vowels or a vowel and another voiced consonant<sup>**2**</sup>. The realisations [f - v], [θ - ð] and [s - z] were allophonic. It was the only way to get [z], [v] and [ð] because Old English didn't have phonemic [z], [v] and [ð].

- *Wolf* was *wulf* and it would've been pronounced [wulf], *wolves* was *wulfas* and would've been pronounced something like [wulvɑːs].
- *House* (noun) was *hūs* and would've been pronounced [huːs], *house* (verb) was *hūsian* and would've been pronounced something like [huːziɑn] (I'm not sure though).
- *Bath* (noun) was *bæþ* and pronounced [bæθ], *bathe* was *baþian* and would have been pronounced [ˈbɑ.ði.ɑn].

As you can see, Old English was a heavily inflected, but a very phonetic language.

- *Close* (verb) was *clȳsan* and was pronounced [ˈklyː.zɑn], phonetically.
- *close* (adj) was *clȳs*, pronounced [klyːs], phonetically.

There are many other examples such as *grass graze, glass glaze, belief believe, life lives, leaf leaves, wife wives, knife knives, bath bathe, breath breathe, north northern* etc etc.

The endings were later on lost and the voiced sounds remained.

---

<sup>1. In Old English, the letters þ and ð were used indiscriminately by Old English scribes to represent the *th* sound.</sup>
<sup>2. The fricatives [s, f, þ ~ ð] were voiceless elsewhere; at the start or a word, end of a word, and adjacent to a voiceless sound.</sup>

Answer (score 14):

You may be confusing two words that are spelt the same.

- "Closer" (adj), meaning something that is more close (near), has an 'S' sound.
- "Closer" (noun), meaning something or someone that closes (shuts), has a 'Z' sound.

Note also that there is a difference in the way words are pronounced when they are sung. When singing, we break up words on the vowel sounds because you cannot 'hold' a consonant. Instead of "close-ur" it would be "clo - sur". This results in it sounding a little different to how it would be pronounced in speech. In fact, if you look at sheet music that contains lyrics, the words are often shown broken up as they are meant to be sung.

Comment: Put that coffee down. [Coffee's for closers!](https://youtu.be/goFaACJXZiY)

Comment: Seems to me that ‘s’ is one of the few consonants you really can “hold”—but the effect would be very much incongruous in the middle of a love song, as it would remind most English speakers of a snake’s hiss.