# Was "twelve" pronounced as "TPELF"?

Tags: pronunciation, numbers, spelling, phonology

I came across this piece of text and I for the life of me can't understand why "***twelve***" is written **tpelf**. I have encircled other numbers that are strange.

My friend who lives in New York sent me this and told me that "*twelve*" was pronounced with a **P** sound and it has now diverged from how it actually was. He said that "twelve" was **tpelf** but people changed it to **twelve** like we have changed "going to" to "gonna" and "want to" to "wanna".

[image]

Source: *[The History of English Spelling](https://books.google.it/books?id=fNfebt79zdwC&pg=PT83&dq=%22seen%20in%20words%20relating%20to%20two%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG9-_1r4fuAhWCPewKHWq2AUgQuwUwAHoECAYQCA#v=onepage&q=%22seen%20in%20words%20relating%20to%20two%22&f=false)* By Christopher Upward, George Davidson

I have underlined other strange words too. When I search "tpelf" on Google, it says "Linkou Hotel - New Taipei City | Four Points by Sheraton Linkou" and other places and I don't know what to do. How did it come about? Can anyone help me?

Comment: [**W after Consonants**](https://books.google.it/books?id=fNfebt79zdwC&pg=PT83&dq=%22seen+in+words+relating+to+two%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG9-_1r4fuAhWCPewKHWq2AUgQuwUwAHoECAYQCA#v=onepage&q=%22seen%20in%20words%20relating%20to%20two%22&f=false)

Comment: Abbreviated phrases are quite a different phenomenon than sound changes.

Comment: Someone needs to have words with the typesetters for that book. They've really messed it up there. Where it says "Initial T before ..." that's not a p, (look closely and you'll note the lack of a little bit sticking up at the top), but it's also not a wynn like it should be. Looks like they just used a lower-case rho from the Greek alphabet. But then they switched to p for all the type in italics. It's a 2011 edition, so there's no excuse, they can't say that they didn't have the character available in their type case.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your friend is incorrect. It's not **tpelf* with *p*, but ***tƿelf*** with ***ƿ***—*Wynn*—which was the Old English (OE) letter to represent the phoneme /w/.

So *twelve* was ***tƿelf*** <sup>**1**</sup>. *Twenty* was ***tƿēntiȝ*** <sup>**2**</sup>. *Two* was ***tƿā*** <sup>**3**</sup>.

## Historical prelude to *W*

The letter that looks like a *P* is actually:

> ## Ƿ (ƿ)

It's called *[Wynn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wynn)* which was a [runic letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes) in [Old English alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_Latin_alphabet) for the phoneme /w/. 'Wynn' literally means 'joy' and itself would've been written:

> ## *ƿynn*

It's how Old English<sup>**4**</sup> looked like ([Beowulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf)):

> [image: Beowulf]

**Ƿ** can be seen in the first line of 'Beowulf'. The first word is ***HǷÆT*** ('what').

The OE alphabet was based on the Latin alphabet. The Latin alphabet of the time did not have the letter ⟨w⟩, therefore OE scribes borrowed the [rune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes) **⟨ᚹ⟩** to represent the /w/. They adapted it as the Latin letter *Wynn* **⟨ƿ⟩**.

It was still in use after the [Norman Conquest](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/267604/106592), but was soon supplanted by ***uu*** (whence the name *double-u*) under the influence of Normans. Middle English (ME) scribes adopted a practice of writing certain letters using a sequence of a particular short downstroke of the pen/quill, called a [*minim*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/545434/365490). A dotless *i* was a single minim and looked like:

> ## *ʅ*

In particular, minims were used for the following letters:

- i, one minim: *ʅ*
- u/v and n, two minims: *ʅʅ*
- m, three minims: *ʅʅʅ*
- w (double-u), four minims: *ʅʅʅʅ*

This is how minims looked like:

> [image: Minims]

And the word 'minim' itself would've been written:

> [image: 'minim' minims]

In Middle English period, **w** was written with four identical minims i.e. as two U's (*ʅʅʅʅ*), so they called it **double-u** and the name stuck. It would've been written something like:

> [image: double u minims]

Early printers used two V's (*vv*) for the double-u and was later on revamped to a single letter *w*.

In Present day English, it's still called *double-u*.

---

1. The *f* changed to a *v* because of [*intervocalic fricative voicing*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/269044/106592). Old English had a phonetic property called 'intervocalic fricative voicing', whereby non-velar fricatives—*/s, f, θ/*—became voiced when they were flanked by two vowels, or a vowel and another voiced consonant (i.e. OE didn't contrast voiced and voiceless fricatives). So *bath* was *bæþ* and would've been pronounced [bæ**θ**], *bathe* was *baþian* and would've been pronounced [ˈbɑ**ð**iɑn]. *Wolf* was *wulf* and would've been pronounced [wul**f**], *wolves* on the other hand was *wulfas* and would've been pronounced [ˈwul**v**ɑs]. I've explained it in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/269044/106592) to another question. *tƿelf* was followed by a suffix beginning with a vowel which changed the *f* to a *v*.
2. ***ȝ*** is called [Yogh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogh) and it represented the /j/ ('y') sound in this instance: /ˈtweːn.ti**j**/
3. The W in 'two' was pronounced in Old English. The W was lost somewhere between Old and Middle English. There was a sound change through which a /w/ was lost in the environment of a preceding [s] or [t] and a following back vowel ([ɒ ɔ o ɑ u] etc). So 'two' was tƿā and it was pronounced /twɑː/ in Early Middle English, it became /twoː/ and then it lost the /w/ and became /toː/ (the vowel /oː/ was shifted to /uː/ because of the Great Vowel Shift). I have explained the W's in 'sword', 'swore' and 'two' in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/106592)
4. Old English was much more phonetic and highly inflected than Modern English. Every word was spelt how it was pronounced, there were no silent letters in OE.

---

#### References:

- [W - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W)
- [Wynn - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wynn)
- [Old English Orthography - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English#Orthography)
- For minims: [Deciphering two words from their Archaic spellings - ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/545434/365490)
- [Medieval Texts in Contexts - Google Books](https://books.google.com/books/about/Medieval_Texts_in_Context.html?id=vwqAAgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Most modern editions of Old English texts, at least in my experience, replace wynn with a W, which is one of the reasons it's not better known!

Comment: @rjpond: Yes. They do that for the sake of legibility. There was another letter ***þ**orn* (*thorn*, for the *th* sounds) which also looked like a P, so it would be confusing.

Comment: Should also note that in French, the letter is called "double vé", or literally "double V".  (Some other languages do similar.)  Another artifact of it being written as two V's rather than two U's.

Comment: It looks like the next word after "HǷÆT" is "ǷE". Could that be the precursor to the modern word "we"?

Comment: @OmarL It is! The opening can be translated as 'Lo! We of the Spear-Danes...' although there is a whole world of discussion about good ways to translate *Hƿæt* (one recent translation uses 'Bro!'). See https://www.bl.uk/learning/timeline/item126510.html

Comment: @OmarL: The first three words are ***HǷÆT ǷE GARDE***

Comment: May I assume "Lating alphabet" (in this answer) is a simple typo, and not some interesting bunny trail I can explore for several hours?

Comment: Another example the OP may be interested in, is of people mistaking the the pronounciation of old english words is "ye", as in "[ye olde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_olde) tea shoppe" - the "y" being a [thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)), which was later replaced with "th". So "ye" is actually just a different spelling of "the", with more or less the same pronunciation as "the" (ignoring accents).

Comment: @JaminGrey: oops.. that's a typo. my fingers are used to typing *-ing*  lol

Comment: @void I figured, but there's so much cool things to explore, I had to double-check!

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: That's interesting! I didn't know that.

Comment: "What!" is still used as an exclamation - "What what!", "What ho!", etc. I don't think it really needs translation: "What we guard" is the modern English, though some tweaking would make the grammar clearer.

Comment: @Void Prior to digital typesetting, it would have been expensive to produce a typeface that included a rarely used character like wynn.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Indeed. AFAIK, the classical Latin alphabet didn't have a separate U and V, and no W. Germanic influence introduced this new hot German sound rendered as VV, double-Vs, before becoming W. Old English on the other hand had no V, so the W sound was either rendered as a rune or as UU, double-Us. Norman conquest then cemented the use of UU. Thus double-U in English and double-V in other languages.

Comment: /w/ wasn't a new sound; Latin "V" represented both the vowel /u/ and the consonant glide /w/. "U" was a later addition to the alphabet to handle the vowel. I am not aware (or have forgotten) the story behind the addition of "W" and its relation to "V" in various languages.

Comment: @chepner. Jan Misali explores [the full story of W from Phonecian to Maori](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sg2j7mZ9-2Y). It's really interesting.

Comment: Jan Misali also has a good video explaining how W came to be.

Comment: @OrangeDog In the context of Beowulf, *hwaet* is constantly used as an interjection that doesn't link to the rest of the sentence. It seems to be an attention call, like "Hey!" or "Yo!" Beowulf is a very long story with numerous long digressions and side-stories. It probably would originally have been told in parts over several nights, and during the telling people were wandering off to get drinks, having side conversations, and so on, less like a theatrical performance than a band at a bar. One theory is *Hwaet!* means something like "Okay, pay attention, this part is important!"

Comment: @OrangeDog The third word there isn't "guard", it's actually "gar-dena", literally "spear-Danes". The first line of Beowulf translates as roughly, "*Hwaet!* In times long past, we of the Spear-Danes heard of the glory of the clan kings, and how those noble men performed courageous deeds."

Comment: Even today, certain would-be posh "chaps" in England use What? What? as interjection.