# Term for words that seem like they should rhyme because of the way they are spelled, but don't

Tags: word-request, terminology

Some words do rhyme like 'mate' and 'hate' or 'boot' and 'shoot'. But there are other words whose spelling suggests that they should rhyme, but they don't. Examples include: 'hull' and 'pull', 'blood' and 'brood', 'but' and 'put' etc.

I have been wondering about these words a lot recently. Is there any specific name for these words?

Comment: Of interest: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426965/terminology-what-do-you-call-two-words-that-rhyme-but-whose-endings-arent-spel

Comment: Bear in mind you get a misleading impression of what English is all about if most of your interaction with it is through ***text-based websites***. In the *real* world, way more than 99% of all "language" is in fact ***spoken***, so in practice "eye rhymes" aren't something people would often think or talk about. But even if they've never heard that two-word collocation before, the meaning would probably be obvious in any given context.

Comment: Out of interest where do hull/pull or but/put not rhyme?  Both those pairs rhyme here (Scotland).

Comment: I'm from the midwest US and to me hull/pull completely rhyme, but but/put don't. ('but' rhymes with putt, mutt, and cut, but 'put' has a different vowel sound that rhymes with soot and foot, which is going to be real confusing to anyone in the british isles.)

Comment: @DarthPseudonym - sure is. All those rhyme to me, N BrE, but wouldn't to a Southern BrE speaker.

Comment: @TobySpeight et al: southern BrE speaker here. Neither of those pairs rhyme for me. But/put are exactly as Darth states (/ʌ/ and /ʊ/, I think); for hull/pull, "hull" has the same vowel as in "but" /ʌ/ - but that vowel may well be a different one for northern BrE speakers! Meanwhile, "pull" has the same vowel as "book" or "foot" /ʊ/.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - All we need now is a Lancastrian with loook & boook rather than luck & buck & we've got the set;) I'm Yorkshire, but living in London for 30 years I still find it slightly odd that people here can rhyme cup with hat :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are called [**eye rhymes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_rhyme) (or *visual rhymes* or *sight rhymes*). Other examples are *Sean Bean* (pronounced *Shawn Been*), *love* and *move*, *wood* and *food*, *come* and *home*, *bough* and *though* *mind* and *wind* (movement of air) etc.

Comment: I just understood why they are called "eye rhymes". It is because they look like rhymes to the eye but actually they don't rhyme.

Comment: Love and move *used* to rhyme in early middle english but the vowel shift got to 'em and love changed into luv.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: 'Love' used to be written *lufe*, the 'u' was changed into 'o' due to [minim](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271259/106592) confusion.

Comment: The trouble with this phrase is, you may well have to explain what it means.